# How to find and add the node with the same name as a sibling to the find node in c#

Tags: c#, xml

Trying to find the xml node with a name and add the another new node with the same name as a sibling.

Issue: used GetElementsByTagname() method which will give the list of nodes with the name. Looping through the nodes to add a new node with same name as a sibling. It raises an error "**The element list has changed. The enumeration operation failed to continue.**"

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I believe the collection is immutable. You can create a copy of the collection. When you find the elements you want, add them to the collection you have deep cloned. See if you can ToList() the collection to create a copy of your target collection.

Also as the code is not in your question, have you considered using InsertAfter() on the parent node or AppendChild() once you have created your elements?